# What XML Parser would fit my requirements?

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, sax, stax

I am working on a Java project to modify XML files. My requirement is that the program should be able to -

1. Add a specific tag before/after another existing tag
2. Add a specific field (AVP) in an existing tag
3. The modified XML should have the same tag structure.

Based on these two, I have tried using DOM, and while it is working just fine, it is randomizing the tag structure. So if a tag has 10 fields, the placement of the fields becomes randomized when the modified XML is created. Next, I tried SAX, but it's not working as good as DOM was with the first two requirements mentioned above. I am hearing about StAX now. Will StAX work for my requirements? And if not, is there an alternative for these specific requirements?

Comment: what library are you using for this? what programming language? tools?

Comment: Java programming language, since it's a Java project. I have been using several libraries such as guava, Spring and apache libraries.